# Move tool creates new faceless geometry in edit mode. Blender 2.8

Tags: modeling

(building 1st character model) For some reason when i select the bottom of the neck via edge select, and hit G to move/grab, it create copy's of attached vertices and moves those instead of just moving what i selected.

Comment: It most certainly only moves existing geometry. Perhaps you've accidentally created duplicate vertices, for instance by extruding but not moving the new geometry. In edit mode use *Vertex > Merge Vertices > By Distance* to remove duplicate vertices.